# Can NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip in C# be customized?

Tags: c#, system, tooltip, system-tray

Purely out of GUI vanity, I would like to make my task bar tool tip less...well, less "I wear a suit and work at Microsoft"-y. I can't seem to find a setting to do this, but I know that this particular function is relatively new so if anyone knows of a way to change the balloon look and feel I would very much appreciate a link or suggestion! Below is my code:

```
public static void shutdownWarning()
    {
        ToolTipIcon tipIcon = new ToolTipIcon();
        tipIcon = ToolTipIcon.None;
        TaskBarIcon.getInstance().mNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(100, "", "Sending. Please do not shut down.", tipIcon);
    }
```

Cheers!!

badPanda

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, creating easily recognizable UI components that don't leave the user guessing what just popped up is considered an asset, not a liability.  My mom thinks so anyway.

You certainly can do something else, the "popup toaster" window was popular for a while.  You'll get no help from NotifyIcon, just create your own topmost form.  Anything goes.  I wrote some code for [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/7a264203-baec-4760-acaf-10ecd8156741/), might be helpful.